# Generate n rows of NULL in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id, integer, Primary Key, not null
name, character varying
created, timestamp without timezone, not null, default: now()
```

I want to generate n rows with NULL a name field.

I know that I can do:

```
INSERT INTO
  employee (name)
VALUES
  (NULL),
  (NULL)...
```

But I'd prefer to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO
  employee (name)
SELECT
  NULL
FROM
  dummy_table_with_n_rows
```

And I would be able to choose the n.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO
  employee (name)
SELECT
  NULL 
FROM
  generate_series(1,10000) i;
```

Comment: @DanielPatz: Don't miss the variations of the function too. Some are quite neat: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-srf.html