# Connect by level in Postgres on a sequence

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I need to convert a query from Oracle to Postgres which uses `connect by level` on a sequence in Oracle.

I know that `connect by level` is not available in Postgres. I couldn't find an alternate for this using recursive cte.

In Oracle if I run this query.

```
 create sequence ID_SEQ;
 select ID_SEQ.nextval from DUAL connect by level <= 3;
```

I will get the following result

```
1
2
3
```

I need the same in Postgres. Please share some solutions if anyone has any idea.

Thanks in advance
Gokul.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent PostgreSQL syntax to Oracle's CONNECT BY ... START WITH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898681/what-is-the-equivalent-postgresql-syntax-to-oracles-connect-by-start-with)

Comment: @Aleksej: no it's not a duplicate. In this query `connect by` is misused to generate a series of rows  (and it's not even officially supported). This is a lot easier in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: my mistake

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate n rows of NULL in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573945/generate-n-rows-of-null-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct translation of that query is to use `generate_series()` and `nextval()`

```
select nextval('id_seq')
from generate_series(1,3);
```

This will advance the sequence three times.

---

If however the goal is to set a *specific* value for an existing sequence (which requires such a hack in Oracle), just use `setval()`:

```
select setval('id_seq', 3);
```